# How to install mono 5.0.x on Mac using homebrew?

Tags: mono, homebrew

I tried just `brew install mono`, and it appears that the default installs a 4.x version.

Thanks!

Comment: You can download it from Mono's website: https://download.mono-project.com/archive/5.0.0/macos-10-universal/MonoFramework-MDK-5.0.0.100.macos10.xamarin.universal.pkg

Comment: Unless someone updates the script, you are out of hope. Not a question qualified for SO.

Comment: `brew install mono` now installs version 5 :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use [homebrew-cask](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask) to install mono-mdk.

`brew install mono-mdk --cask`

Comment: I did that, it seemed to complete without problem, but left no trace about where I might find an executable.

Password: ....   mono-mdk was successfully installed!

Any ideas?

Comment: Operator error, needed new shell, the install works. Thanks!